# Simple way to connect MacBook Pro laptop to an external display in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, macbook

I would like to know a simple way to connect a MacBook Pro laptop to an external VGA LCD display in Ubuntu 12.04, using the machine's mini display-port and a mini display-port to VGA adapter.  I've acquired both a USB keyboard and a USB mouse. Currently my Apple machine is running only Ubuntu 12.04.

Since I am not familiar with any Linux application designed for this purpose, any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

2014-07-31

Thanks very much for your kind suggestions.  I am under the impression that the hot keys on a MacBook Pro work only in OSX. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Julianloui

Answer (score 0):

After hooking up the cables, go to displays (Settings--> Displays). There, you can set up the monitor. There, shut off the built-in display of the MacBook and clicking on the VGA display and enabling it. You can set up the settings (like the resolution) of the monitor also.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to "System Settings" from Launcher or from Dash and select "Displays" you should be able to select which display you would like to use. Make sure the display is powered on when you try to access it.

Most laptops also have hotkeys to change whether they are using the video output, the built-in display, both, or neither. Best of luck.